# Weird, Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using Axios to send requests to the server. This is the instance I use:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://wagal.com",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.userData.token}`,
  },
});
```

and here is how I use above instance to enable and disable 2fa:

```
function switchTfa(data) {
  if (data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
      return api_request
        .post("/api/user/tfa/enable", {})
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(isLoading(false));
          dispatch(
            userData({
              tfa_enabled: data,
              user_token: store.getState().auth.userData.token,
            })
          );
          console.log("Success");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch(isLoading(false));
          console.log(`error.message`, error.message);
        });
    };
  } else {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(isLoading(true));
      return api_request
        .post("/web-api/user/tfa/disable", {})
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(isLoading(false));
          dispatch(
            userData({
              tfa_enabled: data,
              user_token: store.getState().auth.userData.token,
            })
          );
          console.log("Success");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch(isLoading(false));
          console.log(`error.message`, error.message);
        });
    };
  }
}
```

Now, if I send this request, I get below error:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

If I unquote "Authorization" in Axios instance it works

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://wagal.com",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.userData.token}`,
  },
});
```

Now, if I reload the app and send the request, it throws this 400 error, but if I wrap "Authorization" with quote again, it sends the request, weird!!!

Why after every reloads I get 400 errors sometimes by quoting and sometimes by unquoting "Authorization"?

Thank you

Comment: Certainly the quotes or not have nothing to do with any behaviour changes directly; they just trigger a hot reload or refresh that in turn causes the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the store is not persistent. As I can imagine from your code that state is not maintained globally such as Redux, hence when you refresh then the store is empty.
Ideally when we want access token to be sent for API call then you will have two options,

1. Store the access token as encrypted in local storage
2. Use the browser in-memory storage for a more securing way of access token

You can read about more here : https://auth0.com/docs/security/data-security/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios

Comment: Thank you so much, I am using redux and when I am sending request I have React Native Debugger open, and I can see the Redux state that token is there and exists, I even logged the token to make sure the token exists and it does.